# Missing "Server Certificates" icon in IIS8

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I'm trying to configure SSL on my Windows 2012R2 server, but I can't find the "Server Certificates" icon that I normally use to request and manage certificates. Is there a Feature or Role I need to install to add it to IIS?

[image]

Comment: Are you at the 'Sites' level? `SSL Certificates` is only visible at the top-level.  Click on the name of your server in the left hand pane and you should see it.

Comment: @garethTheRed - The screenshot is from the site level, you can tell by the `SSL Settings` icon which does not exist on the server level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To clarify because there seems to be some confusion here, you need to click on the IIS server - not the site. 
Add your certificate.   Then click on the site that will use it and bind the certificate to that site.